# Return rows which were most recently updated on a given day

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, max

I am stuck on on my SQL/Oracle query..

For this question, the fields which are of interest are `effective_day`(td.ws_date), `ot.valid_from` and  `ot.valid_to.`

There is one record returned for each `effective_day`. The record is valid as long as it was edited on or before the `effective_day` and on or after the `effective_day`.
To find out when it was valid we look at the fields`ot.valid_from` and `ot.valid_to.`

`ot.valid_from <= effective_day <= ot.valid_to`

An `order_no` can be updated multiple times in one day -the `valid_to`and `valid_from` fields are updated accordingly. So for three days the updates for one order could like like this:

```
ID |Order   | Valid From         | Valid To           |
=================================================================
0  |112     | 07-SEP-11 21:13:12 | 08-SEP-11 01:02:11 |
1  |112     | 08-SEP-11 01:02:12 | 08-SEP-11 01:14:12 |
2  |112     | 08-SEP-11 01:14:13 | 09-SEP-11 05:23:51 |
3  |112     | 09-SEP-11 05:23:52 | 09-SEP-11 16:21:13 |
4  |112     | 09-SEP-11 16:21:14 | null               |
```

If I want to return the order detals for `effective_day = 08-SEP-11`. The data returned should be the most recently updated data for that day. So it should be ID 2.

Similarly, if I want to return the order details for `effective_day = 09-SEP-11` then ID 4 should be returned.

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT  
  td.ws_date effective_date,
  ot.ORDER_NO,
  ot.PROCESS_AREA,
  ot.VALID_FROM,
  ot.VALID_UNTIL
  FROM ws_tracker_dates_tab td, ws_tracker_old_tab ot 
  WHERE (ot.VALID_FROM  <= td.WS_DATE)
  AND (ot.VALID_UNTIL IS NULL or (ot.VALID_UNTIL>=td.ws_date))
  AND ot.COMPLETED = 'N'
  AND td.WS_DATE BETWEEN (SYSDATE -30) AND (SYSDATE)
  AND ot.process_area is not null
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `ot.valid_**from** <= effective_day <= ot.valid_to`?  I'm also assuming that your date fields are actually `timestamp` datatypes (not `char`), and that 'not defined' should actually be `null` (and that `null` should be considered hival).

Comment: Hi, yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems like that, use a future date (like `31-DEC-9999`) as the "valid-to" date for the current active/valid entry.

That way, you can always use `between()` to locate the latest entry. Also `ORDER BY` will behave correctly.

If you can't change this, create a view that replaces `null` with the date you selected:

```
select ..., coalesce(valid_to, to_timestamp('31-DEC-9999', 'DD-MON-YYYY')), ....
```

Comment: Hello, 
Yes I am unable to change this, the tables were not constructed by me I simply creating a view from them so I will use your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery in the where clause like the following

```
Where ot.ID = 
    (select max(in1.ID) 
    from ws_tracker_old_tab in1 where in1.Order=ot.Order 
    and in1.VALID_FROM = (select max(in2.VALID_FROM) 
                      from ws_tracker_old_tab in2 
                      where in2.Order =in1.Order 
                      and in2.VALID_FROM  <= td.WS_DATE 
                      and (in2.VALID_UNTIL IS NULL or in2.VALID_UNTIL>=td.ws_date))
```

If you know that the VALID_FROM dates are always going to be unique per order then you can make it a little simpler:

```
Where ot.VALID_FROM = (select max(in1.VALID_FROM) 
                       from ws_tracker_old_tab in1 
                       where in1.Order = ot.Order 
                       and in1.VALID_FROM  <= td.WS_DATE 
                       and (in1.VALID_UNTIL IS NULL or in1.VALID_UNTIL>=td.ws_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with `valid_from` and `valid_to` (especially in consideration that `valid_to` may be null [which should likely mean hival]), is to ignore `valid_to`: Because in this context, it's a **derived** value (something that's not *usually* supposed to be stored in a database).

That said, I believe the following should work for you:

```
WITH max_stamp(effective_date, order_no, stamp) as (
               SELECT a.ws_date, b.order_no, b.MAX(b.valid_from)
               FROM ws_tracker_dates_tab a
               JOIN ws_tracker_old_tab b
               ON b.valid_from < CAST((a.ws_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS TIMESTAMP)
               WHERE a.ws_date BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 30) AND (SYSDATE)
               GROUP BY a.ws_date, b.order_no)
SELECT a.*, b.effective_date
FROM ws_tracker_old_tab a
JOIN max_stamp b
ON b.stamp = a.valid_from    
AND b.order_no = a.order_no
```

Please note that I'm on DB2, and haven't used Oracle, so that may need some adjustment.